Отправка curl в jenkins
У меня есть jenkins pipeline и такая функция
def test() {
    def botToken = '7157804157:****'
    def chatId = '****' 
    def message = "0: commit\\n1: commit\\n2: commit\\n3: commit\\n4: commit\\n5: commit\\n6: commit\\n7: commit\\n8: commit\\n9: commit"
    def encodedMessage = URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")
    def url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot${botToken}/sendMessage?chat_id=${chatId}&text=${encodedMessage}"
    echo "url: ${url}"
    bat "curl -X GET \"${url}\""
}

вывод:
url: https://api.telegram.org/bot7157804157:******/sendMessage?chat_id=*****&text=0%3A+commit%5Cn1%3A+commit%5Cn2%3A+commit%5Cn3%3A+commit%5Cn4%3A+commit%5Cn5%3A+commit%5Cn6%3A+commit%5Cn7%3A+commit%5Cn8%3A+commit%5Cn9%3A+commit

но когда отправляется curl, то запрос уже такой
web-demo>curl -X GET "https://api.telegram.org/bot7157804157:******/sendMessage?chat_id=*****&text=0A+commitCn1A+commitCn2A+commitCn3A+commitCn4A+commitCn5A+commitCn6A+commitCn7A+commitCn8A+commitCn9A+commit" 

Почему изменяется и как передать в curl те же данные, что я вижу и в выводе url?
